# How to setup twitter and github username Jekyll

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

So I'm exploring what we can do through github hosting static website service.
However, I could'nt find an explanation why in the **_config.yml** file,
the setting *twitter_username* and *github_username* aren't rendering nor working.

This is my _config.yml file :

```
title: Hacker theme
description: This is Bilal MAJJAD personal page
show_downloads: false
google_analytics: G-QTNDKBBZ67
theme: jekyll-theme-hacker
twitter_username: byhlel
github_username: byhlel
```

My guess is that it's not supported by the Hacker theme of Jekyll or maybe I need to import something else?

source code (https://github.com/byhlel/page/blob/main/_config.yml).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported/in the code, see https://github.com/pages-themes/hacker - you'd need to access the variable from the somewhere, e.g. the layout.

See https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables:

Example:

`<div>https://twitter.com/{{ site.twitter_username}}</div>`

Not sure if this is the correct URL to a profile though.